# How to view R source code

Tags: r

I'm trying to view a source code. For example for cook.distance(). This is what I have tried

```
cooks.distance
function (model, ...) 
UseMethod("cooks.distance")
<bytecode: 0x3f25b5c>
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

then i tried:

```
 debug(cooks.distance)
```

and got nothing. Then I tried:

```
 methods(cooks.distance)
 [1] cooks.distance.glm* cooks.distance.lm* 

 Non-visible functions are asterisked
```

then I tried:

```
 lm:::cooks.distance.default
 Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘lm’
```

someone told me lm was in the MASS package so I tried the following:

```
 MASS:::cooks.distance.default
 Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
 object 'cooks.distance.default' not found
```

how can I view the source code? I tried to look in the source code but could not locate the function?

Comment: Looks like it's in the `stats` package, not `MASS`. Try `stats:::cooks.distance.lm`.

Comment: `getAnywhere(cooks.distance.lm)`

Comment: This is a very similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173683/how-can-i-read-the-code-for-summary-for-a-data-frame and is part of the r-faq tag

Comment: Linked to wrong canonical question; should be **[How can I view the source code for a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`getAnywhere(cooks.distance.glm)`

From here: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Object-orientation