# How does R's lm function handle factor levels (in C_Cdqrls?)?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

Or in other words: which algorithm is used in this case? I guess they use discriminant analysis as discribed e.g. in chapter 4.4. in James et. al. "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R"?

After input from comments I could also restate the question as follows:

- the first part of the magic appears in `ans <- .External2(C_modelmatrix, t, data)` (in `model.matrix.default`) where the model changes according to factor levels => **I think I understand this part.**
- The second part still involves `z <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y, tol, FALSE)` and I would not expect, that linear regression and discriminant analysis are the same on the maths level. 
  **Do I miss something obvious**? Again, my `stats` package is a binary, I do not have access to the source code...

I found quite useful explanations in this [article](http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2016/07/20/lm-in-R.html), but at some point it only states

> ... This [factor] deconstruction can be a complex task, so we will not
>   go into details lest it take us too far afield...

I could not find anything in the documentation and I was not able to understand what's going on using `debug(lm)`
What I understand using a reproducible example:

```
n <- 10
p <- 6
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out = n) + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
y <- c(1:3)
y <- sample(y, n, replace = TRUE)
z <- 10*y*x + 10*y + 10 + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
debug(lm)
fit <- lm(z ~ x*y)
```

After `mt <- attr(mf, "terms")` it looks like

```
mt
# ...
# attr(,"dataClasses")
#         z         x         y 
# "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

whereas after

```
n <- 10
p <- 6
set.seed(1)
x <- seq(0, 20, length.out = n) + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
y <- c(1:3)
y <- sample(y, n, replace = TRUE)
z <- 10*y*x + 10*y + 10 + rnorm(n, 0, 1)
y <- as.factor(y)
debug(lm)
fit <- lm(z ~ x*y)
```

and `mt <- attr(mf, "terms")` looks like

```
mt
# ...
# attr(,"dataClasses")
#         z         x         y 
# "numeric" "numeric"  "factor"
```

But then it seems, they always call `lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...)` and there `z <- .Call(C_Cdqrls, x, y, tol, FALSE)` which I thought only works without factors.
The link above nicely explains everything down to the model matrix and qr-decomposition which I thought does not work in case of factors.

**Edit**: The model matrix after `x <- model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)` already differs. In case of numerics

```
x
   (Intercept)          x y       x:y
1            1 -0.6264538 3 -1.879361
2            1  2.4058655 1  2.405866
3            1  3.6088158 2  7.217632
4            1  8.2619475 1  8.261947
5            1  9.2183967 1  9.218397
6            1 10.2906427 2 20.581285
7            1 13.8207624 1 13.820762
8            1 16.2938803 2 32.587761
9            1 18.3535591 3 55.060677
10           1 19.6946116 2 39.389223
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 3
```

In case of factors

```
x
   (Intercept)          x y2 y3      x:y2       x:y3
1            1 -0.6264538  0  1  0.000000 -0.6264538
2            1  2.4058655  0  0  0.000000  0.0000000
3            1  3.6088158  1  0  3.608816  0.0000000
4            1  8.2619475  0  0  0.000000  0.0000000
5            1  9.2183967  0  0  0.000000  0.0000000
6            1 10.2906427  1  0 10.290643  0.0000000
7            1 13.8207624  0  0  0.000000  0.0000000
8            1 16.2938803  1  0 16.293880  0.0000000
9            1 18.3535591  0  1  0.000000 18.3535591
10           1 19.6946116  1  0 19.694612  0.0000000
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 2 3 3
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$`y`
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

**Edit 2**: Part of the question can be also found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/416762/209028)

Comment: One of the first steps within lm is constructing the design matrix which involves dummy encoding of factors. The design matrix is of course numeric and is what is passed to lm.fit.

Comment: Perhaps see `?contrasts`? Or perhaps just look at `model.matrix(z ~ x * y)` using your example data?

Comment: @Roland Good point, but see my edit.

Comment: @Gregor I understand, the model matrix already differs, which makes sense. But I still can't proceed. See my edits.

Comment: I don't understand. The model matrix obviously differs depending if you pass numeric variables or factor variables. You can find the source of R and recommended packages on github: https://github.com/wch/r-source

Comment: @Roland I can't find `modelmatrix` or `Cdqrls` at that [github](https://github.com/SurajGupta/r-source/tree/master/src/library/stats/src) location. Do I miss something? And I can't find it in `C:\R\R-3.5.1\library\stats` (with subfolders demo, help, html, libs, Meta, R, tests)

Comment: [Here's the code in github](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/59fa5da9356244128d6d4e4ae20dad580b3f85d9/src/library/stats/R/models.R#L617), you can also view it by typing `model.matrix.default` in your R console. Tempted to close as a duplicate of the FAQ on [How to read the source code of an R function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11173683/903061).

Comment: @Gregor thanks, I will have a look at it. However, I don't think that this question is a duplicate, because I want to understand what R implemented. In your code-link the work is done in line 669, the .Call...

Comment: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/src/model.c#L327

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/416762/209028), I realized, that the answer is simple:

If the factors belong to the variables (predictor variable), the `model.matrix` just gets larger. Thus is it is clear, that `C_Cdqrls` can handle the model matrix.

Only if the dependent variable(s) contain factors, linear regression or `lm` doesn't work properly and discriminant analysis is one possibility. (At a first glance it seems, that `stats::glm` uses a logit model.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis):

> Discriminant function analysis is very similar to logistic regression,
>   and both can be used to answer the same research questions.
>   Logistic regression does not have as many assumptions and restrictions
>   as discriminant analysis. However, when discriminant analysis’
>   assumptions are met, it is more powerful than logistic regression.
>   Unlike logistic regression, discriminant analysis can be used with
>   small sample sizes. It has been shown that when sample sizes are
>   equal, and homogeneity of variance/covariance holds, discriminant
>   analysis is more accurate. With all this being considered, logistic
>   regression has become the common choice, since the assumptions of
>   discriminant analysis are rarely met.

---

Example:

```
x <- seq(0, 10, length.out = 21)
y <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
y <- as.factor(y)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)

# see ??numeric and the ‘Warning’ section in factor:
plot(x, as.numeric(levels(y))[y], ylim = c(0, 1.2))

fit <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
print(summary(fit))

fit_glm <- stats::glm(y ~ x, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = df, control = list(maxit = 50))
print(summary(fit_glm))

df$glm.probs <- stats::predict(fit_glm, newdata = df, type = "response")
df$glm.pred = ifelse(glm.probs > 0.5, 1, 0)
points(x, df$glm.pred + 0.05, col = "red")
```